# Not able to load dll from jar in java

Tags: java, dll, jar

I am integrating an API, where I have to post the request to the service provider.
The service provider has given a .jar and .dll file to be included for the set-up.
When I de-complie the .jar, I see that one of the files is trying to load the dll in a static block.
 static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("dllFile");
    }

Now my problem is, the program gets stuck at the point of dll loading and ends abruptly.

I have Windows 7 64-bit system. Hence, I have put my dll file in SysWOW64(I have also tried putting the dll in System32, but that also did not help) and the jar is present in my jre/lib path, but this does not work
Any pointers on what could be going wrong here.

Thanks,
Akshay

Answer (score 0):

Start your program with an additional `-Djava.library.path=<path to your dll>`.

```
java -Djava.library.path=C:\path\to\dll -cp lotsofjars my.package.MainClass
```

Comment: when i run this using verbose,I ses that the program goes till the point of loading the files present in the jar, and it stops during the loading of the file which has the static block
static { System.loadLibrary("dllFile"); } After this point, there is no error

Comment: Ok i tried one more thing, removed the jar and dll from everywhere, included the jar in my project as external lib. Put the dll in Windows/System32. Th program still fails at the same point.

Comment: Is there something wrong wit path & classpath variables? Following are the values set in my system.
Classpath: .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin;
Path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.8.2-bin\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_35\bin;